# WooCommerce get_name() function throws an error even though the product exists

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I would be so greatful for any assistance as this is driving me mad. After many hours of troubleshooting, I have narrowed the issue but have no idea why it occurs...

My code iterates through all the products within the woocommmerce store and create an order with a relevant product for a customer. It has stopped working when I updated.

The error log displays
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_name()

my code [in its simplest] to diagnose the issue:

```
//declarations
global $wpdb;
global $woocommerce;
        
//get all product (ids) on system
$all_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'fields' => 'ids',
) );
    
//create an array of the product ids found
$counterOfProducts=0;
foreach ( $all_ids as $id ) {
    $arrayOfProdIds[] = $id;
    $counterOfProducts=$counterOfProducts+1;
}
    
foreach ($arrayOfProdIds as $IdOfproductFromArray) {
    echo '<p>array id value:: '.$IdOfproductFromArray.'</p>';
    //$product = wc_get_product( $IdOfRoductFromArray );
    
    $product = wc_get_product( 30302 );  // this is a test id that I know to exist 
    $theTestproductName = $product->get_name();
    echo $theTestproductName;
}
```

The exception is thrown when get_name is used but the above product is a product that I know exists.

All help is really appreciated.

Comment: Just use [wc_get_products](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) instead. Some [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bwoocommerce%5d%20wc_get_products) on SO. You also perform some unnecessary steps in your code. 
Why push all id's (`$all_ids`) in an array (`$arrayOfProdIds`) via a foreach loop while they are identical and contain exactly the same content.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to look. The array of ids and counter is created so that I have a handle on the ids that are got from available products on the system [this is only a snippet I created to illustrate the issue in the easiest form to explain]. That said, I wrote it about a year ago and take your point, it is still not really necessary, even if you saw the rest of the code [which I am ashamed of :)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use instead [`wc_get_products()` function](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_products-and-WC_Product_Query) to query your products and you will get directly an array of `WC_Product` Objects where you will be able to use the `WC_Product` method `get_name()` like:

```
// Get all published products
$products = wc_get_products( array(
    'limit' => -1,
    'status' => 'publish',
) );

$product_count = count($products); // Get the product count
echo '<p>Count: '. $product_count .'</p>'; // Output

// Loop through the array of product objects
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $product_name = $product->get_name(); // Get product name
    echo '<p>'. $product_name .'</p>'; // Output
}
```

It should better work.

**Note:** There is no need to declare anything.

Answer (score -1):

as per LoicTheAztec, my answer worked but was not the correct way to resolve this issue so I have removed in case it gives an issue to someone else

Comment: Sorry `new` is to be used with Classes, **but not with functions**… So your answer **is not correct** as `wc_get_product()` is a simple function to get the an instance of the product object based on an ID… So please remove that answer as it's not going to help anybody.